# How to add text to a canvas from a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit, tkinter-canvas

So essentially I have this line:

```
StoreItems = random.sample(set(['sword','pickaxe','toothpick','hammer','torch','saw']), 5)
```

Which randomly chooses 5 strings from the list. I want to put those 5 randomly chosen onto my Tkinter canvas as seperate text's with canvas.create_text.

Comment: Are you asking us to write the code for you? If not please show what you have tried and what didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate over the `store_items`:

```
import random
from tkinter import *


store_items = random.sample(['sword','pickaxe','toothpick','hammer','torch','saw'], 5)


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
XBASE, YBASE, DISTANCE = 10, 20, 20
for i, word in enumerate(store_items):  # <-- iterate words using `for` loop.
    canvas.create_text(
        (XBASE, YBASE + i * DISTANCE),
        text=word, anchor=W, fill='blue')
root.mainloop()
```

---

[image: Demo screenshot]

**UPDATE** To make clicking on the word trigger some action, you need to bind a event (`<1>` or `<Button-1>`) to an event handler.

```
import random
from tkinter import *


store_items = random.sample(['sword','pickaxe','toothpick','hammer','torch','saw'], 5)


root = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()
XBASE, YBASE, DISTANCE = 10, 20, 20
for i, word in enumerate(store_items):  # <-- iterate words using `for` loop.
    canvas.create_text(
        (XBASE, YBASE + i * DISTANCE),
        text=word, anchor=W)

def onclick(e):
    found = canvas.find_closest(e.x, e.y)
    if found:
        canvas.itemconfig(found[0], fill='blue')
canvas.bind('<1>', onclick)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: This works but how would I add tag binds to each individual word? So that if you clicked one of the words from the list it would preform a specific action.

Comment: @Daijoubu, I updated the answer to add another example that show how to bind / handle click event (change color of the clicked item). If you have another question, please post another question.